# Asterisk voice delay via 3G network issue

Tags: asterisk, voip, linphone, wechat

I build Asterisk system, and running Linphone app on iOS and Android system.

I find some issue on my solution. Only used voice service.

Running WiFi environment voice no any delay, When I accept ringing then immediately hear voice.

But running 3G environment voice had 3~5 seconds delay, and fix Jitter buffer configure on Asterisk, enable it, still not solve this issue.

At same device and environment, used Line and Wechat app,  when press answer call still have voice delay. but more fast than my system.

Codec used min data packet GSM. Enable QoS.

I know maybe the biggest issue is client 3G network quality. and I still find flexible configure, can fix this.

I want running 3G environment on asterisk system, get best no delay experience.

How can I do fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3G network have internal delay.

You can do nothing here.

But usualy it 0.5-1.

Your 3sec delay can be caused by bad 3g connection or overload on 3G or issues with your provider(or you just use 3G connection twice- in and out)